# How to case insensitive git diff in azure repository?

Tags: git, azure, git-diff, azure-repos

For my project I'm using Azure repository for version controlling. When I look at the diff it is case-sensitive which I do not care about.

Is there a way to turn on case-insensitive diff in azure repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a custom diff tool to [perform case insensitive diff](http://Samsung%20Galaxy%20Tab%20A%202019).
And you can put additional options if you want:

```
git config --global difftool.idiff.cmd 'diff -i --unified --ignore-space-change --ignore-blank-lines --ignore-all-space $LOCAL $REMOTE'
git config --global difftool.prompt 0
```

Then:

```
git difftool -t idiff
```

See also:

- "[Git preferences and settings in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-config?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio)" when working with  [Azure DevOps / Azure Repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/?view=azure-devops)
- "[Azure Repos / Repository settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/repository-settings?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)"